# What isn't StackOverflow supporting The Day We Fight Back?

Tags: discussion

I noticed previously that StackOverflow had taken a stand against SOPA and had kind of optimistically hoped that I'd see some message concerning [The Day We Fight Back Against Mass Surveillance](https://thedaywefightback.org/) initiative going on today.

Is StackOverflow not supporting this since unlike the intellectual property side of things mass surveillance isn't a direct threat/concern to StackOverlow?

Comment: There are so many worthwhile causes to get behind. Not saying this one isn't appropriate, but just keep that in mind. :)

Comment: Also keep in mind that SE's policy is kinda that as much as can be possible should be made public, and that people are keeping too much information private needlessly.  (Of course, that's not to say that they are advocating violating privacy.)

Comment: I suppose the question is what should stack exchange do with this one. The GoDaddy issue made the SOPA one obvious, whats the "GoDaddy" with this one?

Comment: SE has put up a banner in the past on the main site for political issues (SOPA) and for the death of a famous person. Those lead to some quite lengthy meta discussions on when exactly this is appropriate, and to some quite unnecessary drama. It might be that SE wants to avoid this now and stays clear of using the main site in this way.

Comment: Happy [Don't Cry Over Spilled Milk Day!](http://holidayinsights.com/moreholidays/February/spilledmilkday.htm)

Comment: They just made a [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange/posts/10103555345730473) and [Twitter posts](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/433273646074036224) about it, FWIW.